# UDP sends 6 additional packets in Wireshark

Tags: wireshark, udp

I am sending UDP packets using ttcp to another machine which is connected via a Cisco router. However, when I analyze the packets sent in Wireshark, there is a UDP packet sent before the payload packets are sent, and 5 packets sent after the payload, which all look like this:

```
159 841.055676000   10.0.1.1    10.0.2.1    UDP 46  Source port: 57128  Destination port: krb524
```

So when I issue the command:

```
ttcp -u -t -p 4444 -n 20 -l 1000 10.0.2.1
```

The transfer looks like this:

- 1 Packet sent with Length 46
- 20 Packets of Length 1046 (as expected)
- 5 Packets sent with Length 46

What are those additional packets? Do they belong to UDP or is it specific to the ttcp implementation? Thanks